# Why does multiprocessing.Queue have no task_done method

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Why does `Queue.Queue` have a `task_done` method while `multiprocessing.Queue` has no such method?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [JoinableQueue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue).

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be: `multithreading` module was implemented very early, `multiprocessing` module came in 2.6 version.

The queue design was slightly corrected for `multiprocessing` and offers better flexibility than the `multithreading`, because you can choose between `Queue`, `SimpleQueue` and `JoinableQueue` depending on your use cases (speed vs reliability).

Now modifing  `multithreading` like this would have caused backwards incompatibility, since `join` and `task_done` methods would have to be removed. Imagine the code needed to be refactored, new tests had to be written, API broken - for me clearly no benefits.